# Ion-tabs select() destroys scroll-content’s margin-top

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-asz9uy?file=pages/contact/contact.ts)

I have a big issue with the Navigation of Tabs.
On my main page (no Tabs) are simple Buttons which deliver different navparams to pre select a Special tab.

If you see the demo and click the 2nd button, the upper part is behind the Header.
That never happens to the first tab, only to the others.
In Detail, its the `margin-top` of the `scroll-Content div`, that gets deleted.

Maybe I’m just doing sth wrong with the Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found another easier way, that doesnt have this issue.

Tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="{{index}}">
   <ion-tab [root]="tabOne"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tabTwo"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tabThree"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tabFour"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Tabs.ts:

```
  ionViewWillLoad(){
     this.index=this.navParams.get("index");
  }
```

and I call the Tabs Page like this:

```
 goToPage(index: number) {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage, { index });
 }
```